# How to call an erlang function in nitrogen?

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

```
-module (blah).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("nitrogen_core/include/wf.hrl").

main() -> #template { file="./site/templates/bare.html" }.

title() -> "Welcome to Nitrogen".

body() ->
#button { id=calcButton, text="Click"}.

imafunction(Param1, Param2) -> %something here%.
```

How do you call the imafunction(Param1, Param2) function with its parameters by clicking the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to do this with a postback.

The simplest way is to change your button to include a `postback` attribute:

```
#button { id=calcButton, text="Click", postback=do_click}.
```

Then you have to handle the postback with an `event/1` function:

```
event(do_click) -> 
    imafunction("first val","second val").
```

But if you wanted to pass the values along with some kind of dynamic data, you can do this one of two ways.

**1)** You can pass it as part of the postback, and pattern match on the postback value.

```
#button { id=calcButton, text="Click", postback={do_something,1,2} }
```

And then pattern match on the postback

```
%% Notice how this is matching the tuple in the postback
event({do_something,Param1,Param2}) ->
    imafunction(Param1,Param2).
```

**or, 2)** You can pass the values as input (say a textbox or dropdown box)

First, add your param fields to send, and make sure your button does a postback

```
body() ->
    [
        #label{text="Param 1"},
        #textbox{id=param1},
        #br{},
        #label{text="Param 2"},
        #textbox{id=param2},
        #br{},
        #button{ id=calcButton, text="Click", postback=do_other_thing}
   ].
```

Then in your `event/1` function, we'll retrieve the values and call your function.

```
event(do_other_thing) ->
    Param1 = wf:q(param1),
    Param2 = wf:q(param2),
    imafunction(Param1,Param2).
```

You can read more about Nitrogen Postbacks and Submitting data at

- [Nitrogen Postback Demos](http://nitrogenproject.com/demos/postback)
- [Nitrogen API Documentation on Requests and Response](http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/api.html#sec-10)